# Android программирование. Вопрос о AppEngine

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

Как я понял приложение получает данные только тогда когда отправляет get или post запрос. Мне стало интересно как организовать асинхронную передачу данных, вот например устройство подписывается на рассылку данных, и как только на сервере происходит некое событие то он оповещает об этом всех подписчиков.
Опишите алгоритм или киньте ссылку. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавлю, что по вопросу не совсем понятно, какого плана задачу вы хотите решить - а от этого зависит выбор наиболее подходящей технологии.

Скажем, если у вас основным является все же мобильное приложение, а с сервера надо оповещать о каких-то событиях - вполне может подойти служба Google Cloud Messaging (https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). Неплохие материалы на русском:

http://habrahabr.ru/post/116106/

http://habrahabr.ru/post/147585/

http://habrahabr.ru/post/213027/

Answer (score 1):

Для этого вы используете, обычно, Google App Engine Channel API.

Описание API для Java:

- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/

Пример серверной части:

```
public class TicTacToeServlet extends HttpServlet {
  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    // Game creation, user sign-in, etc. omitted for brevity.
    String userId = userService.getCurrentUser().getUserId();

    ChannelService channelService = ChannelServiceFactory.getChannelService();

    // The 'Game' object exposes a method which creates a unique string based on the game's key
    // and the user's id.
    String token = channelService.createChannel(game.getChannelKey(userId));

    // Index is the contents of our index.html resource, details omitted for brevity.
    index = index.replaceAll("\\{\\{ token \\}\\}", token);

    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    resp.getWriter().write(index);
  }
}
```

Пример клиентской части:

```
<body>
  <script>
    channel = new goog.appengine.Channel('{{ token }}');
    socket = channel.open();
    socket.onopen = onOpened;
    socket.onmessage = onMessage;
    socket.onerror = onError;
    socket.onclose = onClose;
  </script>
</body>
```

Естественно, что для решения этой задачи вы можете использовать и другие коммуникационные фреймворки, библиотеки и решения. В том числе:

- ZeroMQ;
- RabbitMQ;

GAE Channel это просто стандартное решение от Google, которое хорошо интегрировано в GAE-инфраструктуру, но еего использование, разумеется, не обязательно.